# Migrating data between databases not increasing a performance

Tags: performance, postgresql

I used to have a PostgreSQL 9.2 database with 3 tables:

```
A - contains 12 millions records
B - contains 24 millions records
C - contains 20 millions records
```

Tables are connected like:

```
A (one to many) B
B (one to zero/one) C
```

I have decieded to archive/migrate older data to 2nd database to speed up my main database (less data = better performance).

After I have migrated about 20% of data from every table, I have done `VACUUM ANALYZE` on my main database tables to clean up a little bit.

I thought that next 20% will be much faster to migrate.... I was wrong. Every next percent of data to archive process slower and slower...

I thought maybe `VAACUM FULL` is needed here, but I have read it is not recommended to it. What is more it is a very slow query and requires almost double of disk space (it creates a new table then delete old one).

What can be a reason of slower processing despite the less data left? Am I missing some step which can increase my database speed after migration? Some kind of clean up other then `VACUUM ANALYZE`

Need to specify that I have measure time of processing 3 steps: selecting a data to copy from main database, inserting into 2nd database, delete from main database.

Selecting a data is a problem.

About archiving process:

1. I select a A table rows older then x days. Copy it and remove then.
2. Then I select a B rows connected to A rows selected before. Copy it and remove then.
3. Last I select a C rows connected to B rows selected before. Copy it and remove then.

**Conf:**

8GB RAM.

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
work_mem = 32MB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_segments = 32
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 2.0
```

Comment: Post the SQL migration code and those tables definitions.

Comment: As I understand those 3 steps are independent of each other. Are they? And that you found step number 1 to be the culprit?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Step 1 and 2 are connected - `insert into A from select....`. However I tried a run a `select` independent and figure out that it lasts about 2 min where `insert` + `select` lasts 2,5 min

Comment: If steps 1 & 2 are *connected*: is there a FK-constraint between the two? In the correct *direction* ? Is there a *supporting index* for this FK ?

Comment: @joop B has a FK on A PK. C has a FK on B PK. There are index on both FK i have mentioned

Comment: I don't know how many connected clients you have, and it could be your complete working set fits in RAM, but you are slightly overcommitting memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out where the time is spent. Is it the `SELECT` to find the rows in B and C? Is it the `DELETE`?

Once you have found the problematic statement, look at the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for it; it will tell you were the time is spent.

Deleting rows from a table does not make it smaller and does not necessarily speed up queries on the table. What *may* help is `VACUUM (FULL)`, particularly if there are sequential scans. You don't have to run it on *all* tables in the database; if space is a problem, you can tun it on one table after the other.
But first look at the execution plans to see if that will help at all.

Comment: I have checked a query planner - it is using index scan only. Is it possible that `REINDEX` is needed in this case?

Comment: It is possible, particularly if the index scan scans greater portions of the index. Hard to say without execution plans.